# c# how to color each lines in richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I need to color each line depends on the last char in each string form list. This is my code and it's always make the last line green. What's wrong with it?

```
List<string> plik = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
        string pom;
        int size = plik.Count;
        richTextBox1.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += "[" + i.ToString() + "]" + "  " + plik[i] + Environment.NewLine;
            pom =plik[i];
             richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i), richTextBox1.Lines[i].Length);
           // richTextBox1.Select(0, pom.Length);
            if (pom.Substring(pom.Length - 1) == "n")
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = pom.Substring(pom.Length - 1) == "n" ? Color.Red :Color.Red;
            }
            if(pom.Substring(pom.Length - 1) != "n")
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = pom.Substring(pom.Length - 1) != "n"?Color.Green:Color.Green;                  
            }
        }
```

Comment: _richTextBox1.Text += _ Boom. Never modify the Text!!!! Or else you will lose any formatting. You can Select (like you do below and then swap the SectedText, though.

Comment: `Always makes the last line green` really? [If I compile this code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hXHqy8) I get [this output](http://i.imgur.com/1n531J5.png). In any case, I think you should first [learn to use breakpoints](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+the+visual+studio+debugger&oq=how+to+use+the+visual+studio+debugger&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.3343j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and step through your code.

Comment: Also, why do you have so much redundant code? You check the last character of the current line **four times**. You only need to check it once. `richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = (pom.Substring(...) == 'n') ? Color.Red : Color.Green` is all you need. You don't need a separate, individual `if` statement -- you've already determined whether the last character is an `n` or not. Then once you're inside your if statements you check it again, and on top of that you assign the same color regardless of the result of that ternary expression.

Answer (score 1):

just replace

```
richTextBox1.Text += "[" + i.ToString() + "]" + "  " + plik[i] + Environment.NewLine;
```

by

```
richTextBox1.AppendText("[" + i.ToString() + "]" + "  " + plik[i] + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the text instead of modifying it in whole. Using `+=` will replace the entire string and hence you'll lose the set color each time. Use `AppendText` instead.

Also you can remove the unnecessary `if`s in your code. This should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText("[" + i.ToString() + "]" + "  " + plik[i] + Environment.NewLine);
    richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i), richTextBox1.Lines[i].Length);
    richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = plik[i][plik[i].Length - 1] == 'n' ? Color.Red : Color.Green;
}
```